# WooCommerce iOS OAuth

Tags: ios, wordpress, oauth, woocommerce

I am trying to create an application using the WooCommerce RESTful APIs. I have embedded the AFOAuth1Client for the OAuth authentication but, every time I make a service call for a path, say "products, I get an invalid signature error from WooCommerce. I hit this error only when the WooCommerce RESTful APIs version is v3(EX: http://localhost/wordpress/wc-api/v3). But, if I use v2, I get the response and can see the list of products available. How can I go about making this to work?
Thanks